# AngularJS content doesn't always appear, randomly shows up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a bunch of Angular JS content, and most of it is working fine, when it appears. Sometimes, however, when I refresh the page, all of it simply disappears, and it seems like the AngularJS stopped working all of a sudden. After this, I tried refreshing the page a few more times, and after a few clicks, it finally came back. However, if I try refreshing again after this, the same as before happens.

I'm not really sure what information I can given you that will be relevant, so please let me know if you would like to see the code.

EDIT:

Some of the stuff I thought I could get help with: 
1) Has something like this occurred to anyone else before? 
2) Does placement of the angularJS scripts inside the HTML document make a difference here?

---

EDIT:

Here are the warnings when the content doesn't show up:

```
13:38:38.499 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-inner-spin-button'.  
Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:153
13:38:38.499 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-cancel-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:163
13:38:38.500 Unknown property '-moz-osx-font-smoothing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:279
13:38:38.501 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:923
13:38:38.501 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:938
13:38:38.501 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:947
13:38:38.502 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2325
13:38:38.502 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2343
13:38:38.502 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:2381
13:38:38.502 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:2384
13:38:38.502 Expected end of value but found '�'.  Error in parsing value for 'line-height'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2405
13:38:38.502 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2442
13:38:38.503 Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2737
13:38:38.503 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2746
13:38:38.503 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2766
13:38:38.503 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:3194
13:38:38.503 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:3420
13:38:38.504 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4736
13:38:38.504 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4737
13:38:38.504 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4764
13:38:38.504 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4765
13:38:38.504 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4772
13:38:38.504 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4773
13:38:38.504 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4780
13:38:38.505 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4781
13:38:38.505 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4788
13:38:38.505 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4789
13:38:38.505 Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4795
13:38:38.505 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5357
13:38:38.505 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5365
13:38:38.505 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5434
13:38:38.505 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5438
13:38:38.505 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5504
13:38:38.505 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5508
13:38:38.506 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5774
13:38:38.506 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5778
13:38:38.506 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5779
13:38:38.506 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5780
13:38:38.506 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5782
13:38:38.506 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5788
13:38:38.506 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5789
13:38:38.506 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5790
13:38:38.506 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5792
13:38:38.506 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5799
13:38:38.506 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5853
13:38:38.564 GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js [HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified 452ms]
13:38:38.564 GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.15/angular.min.js [HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established 156ms]
13:38:39.153 Error: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.15/angular.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
13:38:39.160 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. summary_page.html:29
```

Here are the warnings when the content DOES show up:

```
13:41:21.953 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-inner-spin-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:153
13:41:21.953 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-cancel-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:163
13:41:21.953 Unknown property '-moz-osx-font-smoothing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:279
13:41:21.955 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:923
13:41:21.955 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:938
13:41:21.955 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:947
13:41:21.957 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2325
13:41:21.957 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2343
13:41:21.957 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:2381
13:41:21.958 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.css:2384
13:41:21.958 Expected end of value but found '�'.  Error in parsing value for 'line-height'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2405
13:41:21.958 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2442
13:41:21.958 Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2737
13:41:21.958 Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2746
13:41:21.958 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:2766
13:41:21.959 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:3194
13:41:21.960 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:3420
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4736
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4737
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4764
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4765
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4772
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4773
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4780
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4781
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4788
13:41:21.963 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4789
13:41:21.963 Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:4795
13:41:21.964 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5357
13:41:21.964 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5365
13:41:21.965 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5434
13:41:21.965 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5438
13:41:21.965 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5504
13:41:21.965 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5508
13:41:21.965 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5774
13:41:21.965 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5778
13:41:21.965 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5779
13:41:21.965 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5780
13:41:21.966 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5782
13:41:21.966 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5788
13:41:21.966 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5789
13:41:21.966 Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5790
13:41:21.966 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5792
13:41:21.966 Expected 'none' or URL but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5799
13:41:21.966 Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.css:5853
13:41:22.010 GET http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js [HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified 31ms]
13:41:22.010 GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.15/angular.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 47ms]
13:41:22.282 Error: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.15/angular.min.js is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
13:41:22.290 Unknown property '-moz-border-radius'.  Declaration dropped. summary_page.html:29
```

Comment: Do you have javascript errors? What about network logs? Do you have some caching enabled? Mess with your code until you get more hints of what is going on, eg: comment out large parts of code, disable caching, remove the css etc. It's impossible for us to help otherwise.

Comment: @AlexC, I don't get outright errors, just some warnings. I've added them above.

Comment: @AlexC, as you can see, most of the errors are due to Bootstrap, which I haven't messed around with. There are some errors at the bottom about "being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL"

Comment: Is AngularJS properly loaded every time (the actual JavaScript files)? Do you have more than one web server sitting behind a load balancer? Where/how is AngularJS served/hosted?

Comment: @superEb I just upload it via the link in my HTML head. And the problem isn't that AngularJS never works. It does work sometimes, so it's not fully that I'm having a problem with AngularJS. 

And fyi, I'm doing all of this inside 1 HTML document, no separate JS files.

Comment: We're not quite speaking the same language. What are the `src` links (in your `<script>` tags) you're using to include AngularJS in your page? Is it a location under your control, or are you pulling AngularJS from a hosted service? Can you provide some of your HTML in the question?

Comment: @superEb, maybe it wasn't clear, but I said that it's uploaded via a link, so it's from the AngularJS website, I'm not hosting it on my own computer.